# Using fprintf with a combination of a double-array and a cell-array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Using `fprintf` I want to produce an output that looks like this:

> names abc and numbers 1
>   names def and numbers 2
>   names ghi and numbers 3

This is the code I tried using to achieve this:

```
names= {'abc','def','ghi'}
numbers = [1 2 3];
fprintf('names %s and numbers %2.2f \n',names{1:3},numbers)
```

unfortunatly the output it produces looks like this:

> names abc and numbers 100.00
>   names ef and numbers 103.00
>   names hi and numbers 1.00
>   names  and number

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Or is it even possible to combine `fprintf` with cell-arrays? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at what you are passing to `fprintf`, it is simply in the wrong order, and numbers creates one parameter not three individual:

```
>> names{1:3},numbers

ans =

abc


ans =

def


ans =

ghi


numbers =

     1     2     3
```

Instead use:

```
C=names
C(2,:)=num2cell(numbers)
fprintf('names %s and numbers %2.2f \n',C{:})
```

If you typie in `C{:}` you will see the individual parameters in order:

```
>> fprintf('names %s and numbers %2.2f \n',C{:})
names abc and numbers 1.00 
names def and numbers 2.00 
names ghi and numbers 3.00 

>> C{:}

ans =

abc


ans =

     1


ans =

def


ans =

     2


ans =

ghi


ans =

     3
```

Answer (score 2):

The ouput you are seeing is interesting in itself: it resolves `abc` as a string, then `d` as it's ASCII number, then `ef` again as string and `g` as number, then `hi` as string, `1` as number and the latter two fizzle as MATLAB can't see `2` as a string. This implies an important thing of `fprintf`: it takes its arguments in column-major order.

So with that in mind we try creating a cell array of e.g.

```
for ii=numel(numbers)-1:1
    tmp{ii,2} = numbers(ii);
    tmp{ii,1} = names{ii};
end
```

which unfortunately results in an error that `fprintf` can't work with cell arrays. I'd go with a trusty `for` loop:

```
names= {'abc','def','ghi'} ;
numbers = [1 2 3];
for ii=1:numel(numbers)
    fprintf('names %s and numbers %2.2f \n',names{ii},numbers(ii))
end

names abc and numbers 1.00
names def and numbers 2.00
names ghi and numbers 3.00
```